# Filter data per day per ID from a data table and count the no of rows in R

Tags: r

I have a `data table`,I need to count the no of rows per ID per day but somehow i am unable to do it.
The code which i am using is

```
Res=foreach(j=1:length(uniquetimestampnumber)) %dopar% 
   { ANALYSIS[,length(TIMESTAMP),by=list(ID)]}
```

the `data table` looks like this

```
    TIMESTAMP    ID
8/5/2014 17:45  28808
8/5/2014 18:00  28808
8/5/2014 18:15  69821
8/5/2014 18:30  69821
8/5/2014 18:45  69821
8/5/2014 19:00  56247
8/5/2014 19:15  56247
8/5/2014 19:30  56247
8/5/2014 19:45  56247
8/5/2014 20:00  56247
8/5/2014 20:00  28808
8/5/2014 20:15  28808
8/5/2014 20:30  28808
8/5/2014 20:45  28808
8/5/2014 21:00  69821
8/5/2014 21:15  69821
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .N,list(Day=as.Date(TIMESTAMP, '%d/%m/%Y'), ID)]
#          Day    ID N
#1: 2014-05-08 28808 6
#2: 2014-05-08 69821 5
#3: 2014-05-08 56247 5
```

Or may be

```
setDT(df)[,Day:=as.Date(TIMESTAMP, '%d/%m/%Y')]
setkey(df, Day, ID)[, .N, by=list(Day, ID)]
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(TIMESTAMP = c("8/5/2014 17:45", "8/5/2014 18:00", 
"8/5/2014 18:15", "8/5/2014 18:30", "8/5/2014 18:45", "8/5/2014 19:00", 
"8/5/2014 19:15", "8/5/2014 19:30", "8/5/2014 19:45", "8/5/2014 20:00", 
"8/5/2014 20:00", "8/5/2014 20:15", "8/5/2014 20:30", "8/5/2014 20:45", 
"8/5/2014 21:00", "8/5/2014 21:15"), ID = c(28808L, 28808L, 69821L, 
69821L, 69821L, 56247L, 56247L, 56247L, 56247L, 56247L, 28808L, 
28808L, 28808L, 28808L, 69821L, 69821L)), .Names = c("TIMESTAMP", 
"ID"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))
```

Comment: It works but its quite slow just for 3 ID's and 100 days of data.What if i had 1000 ID per day? say 1000 ID's for 100 days of data

Comment: @KaushalSharma  I am a bit surprised.  How big is your dataset?   `data.table` is fast for bigger datasets.

Comment: i have dataset with 2 lakh records

Comment: @KaushalSharma  I updated with `setkey`. Please check if that improved the speed.

Comment: does your modified code mean first make new column with "day" then using setkey do filter and count?

Comment: @KaushalSharma  Yes, and use `setkey` which should be faster.